# How do I get jQueryUI to display a dialog when something long running is executing in the main thread?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My code is doing something very expensive - building a whole bunch of UI elements - so I want to display a dialog to say to "Please wait".

This, obviously, doesn't work:

```
$(function () {

  $("#pleasewaitdialog").dialog({
    'modal': true,
    'autoOpen': false,
  });

  alert("test program started");

  // open the dialog
  $("#pleasewaitdialog").dialog("open");

  // simulate doing something expensive;
  for (var i=0; i<500000000; i++);

  // close the dialog
  $("#pleasewaitdialog").dialog("close");

  alert("test program ended");
});
```

The UI won't update because it's blocked doing the for loop.

I tried this:

```
$(function () {

  $("#pleasewaitdialog").dialog({
    'modal': true,
    'autoOpen': false,
  });

  alert("test program started");

  // open the dialog
  $("#pleasewaitdialog").dialog("open");

  setTimeout(function () {
    // simulate doing something expensive;
    for (var i=0; i<500000000; i++);

    // close the dialog
    $("#pleasewaitdialog").dialog("close");

    alert("test program ended");
  },1);
});
```

And that actually works fine in Safari (between the two alerts the JQueryUI dialog shows.)  But in Chrome (10.0.648.127 for Mac) the jQuery UI dialog doesn't display. [Update: Actually, this solution works.  You need to make sure you don't have it in a document with a broken `<title>` tag mind (see answers below)]

Comment: Us it possible to display the modal before you start loading all the UI stuff?

Comment: @Seth That's what I'm trying to do, to display the modal dialog, then do the work, then close the dialog.  It sounds simple, but there's a difference (it would seem) between telling the browser to display something and it actually getting round to displaying it.  The problem I'm having is that some browsers are not displaying at all (presumably because by the time they're getting ready to actually show the dialog in the DOM I've done the work and told them to close the dialog again)

Comment: @Mark - I know this probably doesn't help, but your `setTimeout` solution works for Chrome and IE9b1 (although IE9b1 gives me 'script running too long' warnings).  Here's my fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/dhoerster/dPn9m/ .  I don't have a mac, so I'm probably not much help.

Comment: @DavidHoerster Actually, that's very helpful.  The fiddle works on Chrome on my Mac.  The same source code cut and pasted into a single file does not!

Comment: @Mark - what version of jQuery/jQueryUI are you using?  The fiddle used jQuery 1.5.1 and jQueryUI 1.8.9

Comment: I'm using 1.5.1 and 1.8.10 respectively.  And I have a broken <title> tag in my example, which is causing the problem.  Thanks David, you solved it.  (I've added this as an answer below, but I have no idea how to credit you with helping here)

Comment: @Mark - glad I could help.  How about you owe me an +1 down the road?  :)  Just kidding.

Answer (score 4):

jQueryUI (jQuery 1.5.1 and jQueryUI 1.8.10) won't display a dialog in Chrome (10.0.648.127, Mac) if you have a broken `<title>` tag for some reason.

The following code works fine in Safari, but doesn't work in Chrome.

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  

    <script>

    $(function () {

      $("#pleasewaitdialog").dialog({
        'modal': true,
        'autoOpen': false,
      });

      alert("test program started");

      // open the dialog
      $("#pleasewaitdialog").dialog("open");

      setTimeout(function () {
        // simulate doing something expensive;
        for (var i=0; i<500000000; i++);

        // close the dialog
        $("#pleasewaitdialog").dialog("close");

        alert("test program ended");
      },1);
    });

    </script> 

    <!-- the broken close title tag here means that the
         jQuery dialog below won't display on Chrome -->
    <title>Test Dialog</tile>

  </head>

  <body>
     <div id="pleasewaitdialog" title="Please Wait">Reticulating Splines</div>
   </body>

</html>
```